# How does Gradle generate a new task from a task rules

Tags: groovy, build.gradle

In section 19.11. of the 4.2.1 user guide is this task rule example. How is the if predicate able to be true before the rule is even executed. I also noticed that when task groupPing is entered before the task rule the build fails. How are the tasks pingServer1, pingServer2 already created before the rule even starts?

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: ping<ID>") { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.startsWith("ping")) {
        task(taskName) {
            doLast {
                println "Pinging: " + (taskName - 'ping')
            }
        }
    }
}

task groupPing {
    dependsOn pingServer1, pingServer2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per this [book excerpt](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9qFNCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=gradle%20task%20does%20not%20exist%20check%20rule&source=bl&ots=pac7Hwq6xA&sig=PhbeqdgOOEBbVGMrgzMt_cKVSpo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig0a2Wyo_XAhVF_IMKHVkVAY0Q6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=gradle%20task%20does%20not%20exist%20check%20rule&f=false), the mechanism is similar to the `methodMissing` functionality in Groovy and other languages. That is, if the task does not exist, then Gradle will deliberately check the task rules, which can clearly create tasks dynamically.

To address the comment, consider the following `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.addRule("rule 1") { String taskName ->
    println "TRACER xyz before if: ${taskName}"
    if (taskName.startsWith("xyz")) {
        println "TRACER xyz inside if: ${taskName}"
        task(taskName) {
            doLast {
                println "xyz " + (taskName - "xyz")
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.addRule("rule 2") { String taskName ->
    println "TRACER ping before if: ${taskName}"
    if (taskName.startsWith("ping")) {
        println "TRACER ping inside if: ${taskName}"
        task(taskName) {
            doLast {
                println "Pinging: " + (taskName - "ping")
            }
        }
    }
}

task foo {
    println 'foo: config phase'
    doFirst {
        println 'foo: exec phase first'
    }
    doLast {
        println 'foo: exec phase last'
    }
}

task groupPing {
    dependsOn pingServer1, pingServer2
    println 'groupPing: config phase'
}
```

In essence, this does:

- Define "rule 1" which checks the `taskName` (a `String`, not a task!) for prefix `xyz`
- Define "rule 2" which checks the `taskName`for prefix `ping`
- Define task `foo` with some printlns
- Define task `groupPing` with dependencies on dynamic tasks

Here is the output for `foo` (spacing added). It illustrates that, in the configuration phase, Gradle invokes "rule 1" and then "rule 2" to define `pingServer1` and `pingServer2`:

```
$ gradle -q foo 
foo: config phase
TRACER xyz before if: pingServer1

TRACER ping before if: pingServer1
TRACER ping inside if: pingServer1

TRACER xyz before if: pingServer2

TRACER ping before if: pingServer2
TRACER ping inside if: pingServer2

groupPing: config phase
foo: exec phase first
foo: exec phase last
```

Comment: Do you mean Gradle is checking the rule string parameter to verify that the task should be created? In the user guide it says the task rule string parameter is used as a description for the rule. It seems that description is the wrong choice of words for the string parameter. If you are saying that Gradle is checking the task rule then the string parameter must be the rule condition and not a description.

Comment: @paul I have added an example. I don't really understand your question but hopefully this will illustrate.

Comment: OK, so the task rule String parameter is a description not a condition.  There is a gradle build error when the groupPing task is defined before the task rule. Why doesn't the methodMissing functionality work in this case?

Comment: Be sure to understand the Initialization, Configuration, and Execution phases. In the case where `groupPing` is defined first, Gradle will encounter it during the configuration phase. It does not find the dynamic tasks and checks for any rules. My guess is that it does not continue to process `build.gradle`: it just checks the rules at that point. Because there are none, it cannot define the tasks and the build fails.

Comment: Task groupPing is after the task rule in the example you used and shows task groupPing in the config phase. Gradle user guide says the build scripts of all projects which are part of the build are executed during config phase.