# How to handle generically a not found task error within Gradle

Tags: gradle

We're building an archetype pattern using [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This essentially means we have a nested structure with an outer `build.gradle` and an inner `build.gradle`. Is there a way make the tasks from the inner `build.gradle` available as tasks on the outer project?

I'm thinking of using a [`GradleBuild` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.html) in the outer `build.gradle` to invoke the inner tasks but I'm not certain how to parse and load all the tasks from the inner `build.gradle` within the outer one. What I was thinking was just catching the `<task> not found` error on the outer `build.gradle` and then trying to run that task on the inner `build.gradle`. Does anyone know how to catch the `<task> not found` exceptions and run some arbitrary task at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)?

However, it is not necessary to catch that error as you can simply define a task rule that will create any missing task on the run. Simply register a rule like the one below:

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: <task>") { name ->
    task(name, type: GradleBuild) {
        dir = // apply your setup here
        tasks = [name]
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Lukas, that's perfect. I also looked at these resources to understand the subject a bit more for those finding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964357/how-does-gradle-generate-a-new-task-from-a-task-rules